# How to construct a query that checks if relation exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am building an Rails 5 app.
In this app I got a User model and a Subscription model.
I want to be able to get all Users that got an active Subscription.

**User**

has_one :subscription

```
- id,
- name
- email
```

**Subscription**

belongs_to :user

```
- id
- user_id
- title
- active (boolean)
```

I need to be able to do a query like this (below). In other words I need to find all Users that not only got a subscription but also where the active attribute is set to true.

```
User.with_active_subscriptions
```

I think I perhaps need to do a Scope but have no idea how to do it.

Comment: You can always add a scope if you need to. If you're going to use that only once then a scope makes no sense IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy, actually, all you need to do is to use `joins`:

```
scope :with_active_subscriptions, lambda {
  joins(:subscription).where(subscriptions: { active: true })
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you to write a scope in `Subscription` model first:

```
scope :active, ->{ where(active: true) }
```

Then, you can use the above scope in your user class.

```
scope : with_active_subscriptions, ->{ joins(:subscription).merge(Subscription.active) }
```

I prefer this way of writing code as `active` is a property of `Subscription` class. User class shouldn't be concerned with that. This way your code will be better structured and if you need to change the functionality of active scope it needs to be done at one place only.